# android java file change due to size

Tags: java, android, android-studio

"I was editing my app while during that in android studio java file format just changed name is still same but all code is gone something is unusual is there as you can see in screenshot below. A notification pop up saying file size is too large"

[Here is screenshot of app file logo changed to j from c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV3je.png)

Comment: Try rebuild the project.  Build > Rebuild Project

Comment: here the pic.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/jV3je.png

Comment: rebuild didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did there but if you want to recover previous content of MainActivity do following

1. Open MainActivity
2. Right Click on MainActivity tab
3. Click on Local history
4. Click on show history 
   now you can see all of the history of your code for MainActivity and you can replace your content with older(correct) content

Comment: it's saying "contents are identical". code is not available.